# Data extraction loop from e-commerce site with Python

Tags: python

I coded a program that gets the price and name data of the products from the Hepsiburada site. but the data I get is only the data of a "ul" list, I need a loop to get the data of other lists can you help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFV2G.png)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import pandas as pd

header = {"User-Agent":""}

url = "https://www.hepsiburada.com/magaza/hepsiburada?markalar=nike"

r = requests.get(url, headers = header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html" )

st1 = soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"mcontent-src-universal-partials-MerchantTabular-common-Products__container"})

st2 = st1.find("ul",attrs={"class":"productListContent-frGrtf5XrVXRwJ05HUfU productListContent-rEYj2_8SETJUeqNhyzSm"})

st3 = st2.find_all("li",attrs={"class":"productListContent-zAP0Y5msy8OHn5z7T_K_"})

liste = []

for detaylar in st3:

        link = detaylar.a.get("href")
        link_basi="https://www.hepsiburada.com/"
        link_tamami=link_basi+link
        print(link_tamami)
        r1 = requests.get(link_tamami, headers = header)
        
        soup1= BeautifulSoup(r1.content, "html")
        fiyat = soup1.find("span",attrs={"id":"offering-price"}).text.strip().replace("(Adet )","").replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
        print(fiyat)
        urun_adi = soup1.find("h1",attrs={"class":"best-price-trick"}).text.strip()
        print(urun_adi)
        urun_markasi = soup1.find("span",attrs={"class":"brand-name"}).text.strip()
        print(urun_markasi)

        liste.append([urun_adi,urun_markasi,fiyat,link_tamami])
df = pd.DataFrame(liste)
df.columns=["Ürün Adı","Markası","Fiyatı","Linki"]
df.to_excel("özdinamik_fiyat.xlsx")
```

i've been trying for a few hours to loop but i still can't